# Как при использовании класса для получения переменных не использовать постоянно __dict__?

Tags: python

Для работы с переменными класса я постоянно приписываю `.__dict__`

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs.keys():
           setattr(self, key, kwargs['key'])

ent = Entity(a = 1, b = 2)
print(ent.__dict__['a']) #1
```

Можно ли как-то при каждом использовании класса возвращать словарь?

```
print(ent['a']) #1
```

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а чем обычный словарь не устроил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За квадратные скобки отвечает метод `__getitem__`

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs.keys():
           setattr(self, key, kwargs['key'])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def keys(self):
        return self.__dict__.keys()

ent = Entity(a = 1, b = 2)
print(ent['a']) #1
```

Comment: А можно сделать как-то ent.keys()?

Comment: можно например так

Comment: А, ну блин, в принципе и так можно, спасибо. Щас отмечу, как правильный ответ

Comment: Ещё один вопрос. Возьмем a = {'b': 1, 'c': 2} Как допустим при print(ent) всегда получать #{'b': 1, 'c': 2}? Но чтобы возвращалась не строка, а словарь

Comment: принт использует строку из метода `__str__`

Comment: но если тебе нужен словарь - используй словарь как базовый класс словаря

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос в том, как сделать такой класс, чтобы передавать атрибуты в **kwargs, и атрибуты были доступны, как по точке ent.attr, так и как в словаре ent['attr'], и был метод keys(), то можно к примеру сделать так:

**1.** Например:
функциональность словаря можно получить "из коробки" наследованием от базового `dict`, а функциональность атрибутов ent.attr не обязательно делать через setattr для kwargs, достаточно определить метод `__getattr__`, который вызывается при обращении, к несуществующему атрибуту, и возвращая значение по ключу словаря. Всего три строчки, а функциональность полностью та же.

```
class Entity(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self[item]
```

**2.** Например:
функциональность атрибутов ent.attr можно получить наследованием от types.SimpleNamespace, ключи keys() берем из `self.__dict__`, а функциональность словаря получить через метод `__getitem__`, который определяет поведение при доступе к элементу через ключ, возвращая сам  элемент через getattr атрибут

```
import types

class Entity(types.SimpleNamespace):
    def keys(self):
        return self.__dict__.keys()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
```

**3.** Например:
функциональность атрибутов ent.attr не обязательно делать через setattr(self, key, kwargs['key']), проще обновить `self.__dict__` из kwargs с тем же результатом, функциональность словаря определить через тот же `__getitem__`, а ключи  keys() брать как kwargs.keys()

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.keys = lambda: kwargs.keys()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
```

**4.** Например: такой код вообще предпочтителен, мы явно сохраняем все в self.kwargs, и натравливаем на него `__getitem__` `__getattr__` и keys(), не стоит вообще работать с `__dict__` объектов, т.к. потом с таким объектом может быть не удобно и сложно работать

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def keys(self):
        return self.kwargs.keys()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.kwargs[key]

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.kwargs[item]
```

Пример использования:

```
ent = Entity(a = 1, b = 2)
print(ent['a'])  # 1
print(ent.a)  # 1
print(ent.keys())  # dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: Подпишите блоки кода . что в чем.